# Replace directive with ng include

Tags: angularjs, templates

I have a directive that uses a compiled template:

```
angular.
    module("myMod").
        directive("myDir", [
function () {
    "use strict";

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "myTemp",
        controller: "myController"
    };
}]);
```

I no longer need the directive, how would I just include the compiled template with ng-include?

```
<div ng-include="myTemp"></div> //i would have thought this might work...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a full link to the template, if its on the same page like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html"></script>
```

You would just do

```
<div ng-include="'template.html'"></div>
```